# Plotting a constant function in R with curve()

Tags: r, auto-vectorization

so I have an error...

```
f <- function(x){return(1)}
curve(f(x),0,100,xname="x")

Error in curve(f(x), 0, 100, xname = "x") : 
'expr' did not evaluate to an object of length 'n'
```

Which is strange considering that

```
F <- function(x){return(0*x+1)}
curve(F(x),0,100,xname="x")
```

Works just fine... This informed me to think about how R treats data.frame()s.

```
a <- data.frame(1,2,3)
f(a)
# [1] 1
F(a)
#   X1 X2 X3
# 1  1  1  1
```

Meaning that the Function Vectorize() will fix my problem. 
Irregardless this is an acute example of the implicit decisions That R makes, which result in inconsistent behavior.

Comment: From `?curve`: `expr  The name of a function, or a call or an expression written as a function of x which will evaluate to an object of the same length as x.` In your first function, you don't use/evaluate `x`. If you want a constant to be return, this one works: `f <- function(x){x-x+1}`.

Comment: So that's the rub, without strong typing errors can pop up when you don't expect them. Fortunately F<- Vectorize(function(x){return(1)}) explicitly commands the behavior required for Curve().
[typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_and_weak_typing)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the function should return a vector of the same length as a parameter. In your case instead of n, the function always returns a vector of just one. The solution could be

```
 f <- function(x){return(rep(1,length(x)))}
```

Comment: I am almost certain that curve passes the given function a dataframe. Knowing this the weirdness almost makes sense.